# Scapy and Python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

Will Scapy be compatible with Python 3.2? I've been trying to find some info on how it performs, since the Scapy website has rather scarce (if any) info on Python 3.X compatibility, and I didn't come up with anything informative. Has anyone tried using it on Python 3.X and how did it perform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Intrusive edit: Many answers below are outdated. Scapy now supports Python 3. See https://github.com/secdev/scapy**

Python 3 compatibility for parts of Scapy seems to have been [attempted](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.scapy.general/4134).

It's perhaps worth filing a ticket on their [bug tracker](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues) if there isn't one already (I tried searching and didn't find an obvious one, which I thought was surprising).

**Update:** https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/issues/5082/compatibility-with-python-3

Comment: Link to issue is dead. Now at [bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/issues/5082](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/issues/5082/compatibility-with-python-3)

Comment: In [said issue](https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/issues/5082/compatibility-with-python-3) there is mentioned a fork at [github: phaethon/scapy](https://github.com/phaethon/scapy) which you can install via ```pip3 install scapy-python3``` (see [@Eriks Dobelis answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28286710/3423324))

Comment: Answers are outdated ! Scapy has been updated to support Python 3: https://github.com/secdev/scapy

Answer (score 5):

As the developers stated, they will not port Scapy2 to Python3.
I have forked the code for Scapy 2.3.1 and created a version which works with python3. You can install it with pip as scapy-python3 or see the code on https://github.com/phaethon/scapy

Comment: Well this version is now super outdated, whereas the original one https://github.com/secdev/scapy has been updated to support Python 3

Answer (score 2):

For the record, Scapy is now compatible with Python 3, and supports with the same code base (and, obviously, the same API) Python 2.7 and 3.3 to 3.6.

Get the latest version from https://github.com/secdev/scapy or use `pip install --pre scapy` (or `pip3`), and try it!