# Download and install scapy for windows for python 3.5?

Tags: python, download, installation, python-3.5, scapy

I installed python 3.5 for my windows 8.1 computer. I need to install scapy for this version (I deleted all the files of the last one). How do i download and install it? can't find anything that help me to do that no matter how i searched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scapy and Python 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502645/scapy-and-python-3-2)

Answer (score 5):

use 
`pip3 install scapy-python3` 
and you will get it

Comment: Watch out, the version provided with scapy-python3 is super outdated :/ I had to download it from github https://github.com/secdev/scapy

Comment: can you tell me which others modules i have to install to run a program of scapy in windows

Comment: @Yusuf have a look on the doc: http://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#windows

Answer (score 2):

Scapy supports Python 3.3 to 3.6 (and 2.7) but, so far, no release has been made. For now, you have to get the current development version from https://github.com/secdev/scapy and install it.

**Update**: you can now install a 2.4.0 release candidate using `pip3 install --pre scapy` (`--pre` means you accept non-stable release).

**Update**: Scapy 2.4.0 has been released. You can now use `pip3 install scapy`!

Answer (score -1):

<s>Use pip from the command line:</s>

<s>pip install scrapy</s>

Apologies, realised that according to the docs scrapy is not supported on Windows with Python 3.x due to missing dependency (Twisted)

Source: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

Comment: Note that the OP asked for scapy, not scrapy ;)